# Onsubmit show success message on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 forms on a page which i submit by ajax and onsubmit it show a succesful message in a div. the problem is when i click submit on a particualr fomr, it calls all the sucess messages in all the divs. But i want it a particular div to show based on the form that was submitted

```
<tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div id="comment_div"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div id="love_div"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><div id="favorite_div"></div></td>
        </tr>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "int_p_cmt.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {

            $("#comment_div").append("<div class='comment' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>comment!</div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 1000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_call_love.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {

            $("#love_div").append("<div class='love' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>Love !</div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 1000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_fav.asp",
        data: data
        }).success(function() {

            $("#favorite_div").append("<div class='favorite' style='border:1px purple solid; padding:2px; margin:5px;'>favorites!</div>");

            setTimeout(function() { 
                $(".messages").fadeOut(function(){
                    $(".messages").remove();
                }); 
            }, 1000);

            $("input[type=text]").val("");

        });
    });
});
</script>

<tr>
        <td width="160" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><form id="form3" name="form3" method="POST" action="<%=MM_editAction%>">
          <input type="image" name="imageField2" id="imageField2" src="imgs/buttons/loveit.png" />
          <label for="textfield"></label>
          <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
        </form></td>
        <td width="125" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><form ACTION="<%=MM_editAction%>" METHOD="POST" id="form5" name="form5">
          <div align="right">
            <input type="image" name="imageField" id="imageField" src="imgs/buttons/favorite.png" />
            <label for="textfield2"></label>
            <input type="text" name="textfield2" id="textfield2" />
          </div>
        </form></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><form id="form2" name="form2" method="POST" action="<%=MM_editAction%>">
          <input name="comment" type="text" id="comment" size="50" />
          <input name="imageField3" type="image" id="imageField3" src="imgs/buttons/comment.png" align="bottom" />
        </form></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: JS Fiddle test: http://jsfiddle.net/62uH4/1/

Comment: Where is the class "messages" in the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 forms 3 different form submission handlers. When a form is submitted, you don't know which form you have to deal with.

For each of the forms, change this:

```
$("form").on('submit',function(event){...
```

To:

```
$("#formId").on('submit',function(event){...
```

Where `#formId` corresponds to the id of the form.

*P.S. you should try to re-use the form submission handler.*

Comment: when i changed to the formid, when i click on submit, its not able to send to the database and no message in a div shows up

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Bootstrap could be useful here: I am not sure whats your exact requirements are but this is what I think your looking for:

```
        <div class="alert alert-warning" id="showMessage">
        <strong>Warnning</strong> Error Message
    </div>
```

In your Ajax you can do:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$('#showMessage').hide();
});

function FunctionName(){
Ajax({
......
success: function (msg) {
    $('#showMessage').show();
}
});
}
```

To use Twitter Bootstrap you need to download their library and place it into your project here is a link to their website.
[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)